# Display code coverage for @WebMvcTest in Intellij IDEA

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, code-coverage

When I run a `@WebMvcTest` with coverage in **Intellij IDEA** the report would contain coverage information about `@RestController`'s that have been involved in test. But it wouldn't contain any information about `@Service`'s that `@RestController`'s usually call.

Is it possible to setup the coverage so that the resulted reports contain all the affected source code? If not, maybe there is a plugin there that can do it?

Comment: Generally when using `@WebMVcTest` you mock the services (or at least you should), so there is no coverage on the services.

Comment: When I use `@SpringBootTest` in combination with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` instead of `@WebMvcTest` I observe the same behavior

Comment: If those use `@MockBean` instead of regular services there is still nothing to test. Another thing is that intellij might not be able to detect the coverage as it is basically invoking a remote application, so I would suggest using something more robust like JaCoCo or just not include integration test coverage in your test report.

Comment: Please file a feature request in the YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA thank you